# SQL-query to filter on two fields in combination

Tags: t-sql

```
ArticleNumber   Company Storage
 01-01227       12      2
 01-01227       2       1  'filtered by company/storage in combination
 01-01227       5       1
 01-01227       12      1  'filtered by company/storage in combination
 01-44444       5       4  'filtered by not match the articlenumber
```

I want to filter so rows containing (`company = 12` **and** `storage = 1`) and (`company = 2` **and** `storage = 1`) will be filtered out of the result set and also filter on `articlenr`.

This is what I come up with, but sure there must be an easier way to make that query?

```
SELECT  * FROM    MyTable 
where 
    (Company=2 and Storage<>1 and ArticleNumber='01-01227') 
or 
    (Company=12   and Storage<>1 and ArticleNumber='01-01227') 
or
    (Company<>2 and Company<>12 and ArticleNumber='01-01227')
```

The result I'm after:

```
ArticleNumber   Company Storage
  01-01227      12      2
  01-01227      5       1
```

Comment: You said you wanted to `filter out` company=5 and storage=1 and you are returning in the query...

Comment: Sorry, It should be company 2 and storage 1! I have changed it now.

Comment: I've just provided both answers

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I know there was a better way of composing that query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return what you're looking for:

```
select * from t
where articleNumber = '01-01227' and (
  (company != 12 or storage != 1) and
  (company !=  2 or storage != 1)
)
```

Result:

```
ARTICLENUMBER   COMPANY STORAGE
01-01227        12      2
01-01227        5       1
```

There is no need to join in this solution, which keeps it quite fast and performant. Besides you can easily keep adding restrinctions as pairs.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ArticleNumber='01-01227'
AND (Company NOT IN (2,12) OR Storage <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to make this easier is to set up a table called, say `company_storage_exclude` with columns of `Company` and `Storage`.  Then simply populate these values with pairs of `Company` and `Storage` that you want to exclude, and you can then do:

```
select *
from MyTable
where (Company,Storage) not in (select Company,Storage from company_storage_exclude)
and ArticleNumber='01-01227';
```

or:

```
select a.*
from MyTable a
left join company_storage_exclude b
on (a.Company=b.Company and a.Storage=b.Storage)
where b.Company is null and b.Storage is null
and ArticleNumber='01-01227';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    NOT (Company=12 and Storage=1) 
AND 
    NOT (Company=5 and Storage=1)
AND
    ArticleNumber='01-01227'
```

or even better

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    NOT ((Company=12 OR Company=5) AND Storage=1)
AND
    ArticleNumber='01-01227'
```

Comment: missed OP's articlenumber restriction

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
SELECT  * FROM    MyTable 
where 
    ArticleNumber='01-01227'
AND
    (Company IN (2,12) AND Storage <> 1
    OR
    Company NOT IN (2,12)
    )
```

Comment: This query will not filter out the row with articlenumber 01-44444 for some reason..